# ionic 2 local storage unable to set retrieved value to variable

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I am trying to set the value retrieved from .get function into a variable declared outside but unable to do so.

```
var dt;
//retrieve
this.local.get('didTutorial').then((value) => {
  alert(value);
   dt = value;
})

console.log("Local Storage value: "+dt);
```

I'm able to get "true" for the alert, but getting "undefined" for the console.log that is printing outside of the function.

[image]
[image]

One workaround is that I can put all my remaining codes into the ".then function" , but that would be very messy.

**Update(Solution):**

As per ionic api (http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/storage/LocalStorage/) , they use .get to retrieve values.

Since using promises has it's own limitations, by using the following:

```
 constructor(navController) {
     this.navController = navController;
     this.local = new Storage(LocalStorage);
 }
```

and getItem function,

```
localStorage.getItem('didTutorial')
```

You will be able to retrieve it without having to put everything into the callback method.

Comment: Hey, this evaluates to: `Error TS2339: Property 'getItem' does not exist on type 'Storage'.`

Comment: @ThomasModeneis I might not be sure as this is for .beta5 and lower.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading from your localStorage wrapper in this case is asynchronous, which means that the callback passed to `this.local.get` gets called *after* your call to `console.log`. Try placing `console.log` *inside* your callback; it should work then:

```
// retrieve
this.local.get('didTutorial').then((value) => {
  alert(value)
  var dt = value
  console.log("Local Storage value:", dt)
})
```

Also, you'll notice that I changed your `console.log` call arguments. That's because `console.log` accepts 1 or more parameters, and formats them much more nicely when you pass them in instead of concatenating them. Just a pro tip.

Comment: But let's say I wish to do other stuffs than using "console.log" , how would I go about doing it?

Comment: I do know that workaround works , but I wish to do more than console.log , but doing it inside the callback is very messy.

Comment: That's simply how JavaScript works, and there's not much of a way around it. Thankfully, you seem to have knowledge of the Promise interface (i.e., `.then`), which greatly improves readability. Perhaps give [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) a read?

Comment: Also if you could mark this as answered that'd be helpful to me and to other SO users 

Comment: Just letting you know, I found the solution :)

Comment: It was a workaround, though, right? You'll find that "callback hell" is a very real code smell that arises in JavaScript that will be hard to combat :)