# JavaScript/Angular2 LocalStorage can get anything

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I developing an Ionic2 app and am storing an array in local storage, it looks like the following:

Key        |    value
options    |    [option1, option2, option3]

I am trying to get `options` key using:

```
  constructor(nav) {
      this.nav = nav;
      this.local = new Storage(LocalStorage);
      this.optionsArray = this.local.get('options');
      console.log('content of array : '+JSON.stringify(this.optionsArray));
    }
```

What I get in the console:

> content of array : {}

Here is how I set the array in previous pages:

```
 this.optionsArray = ['option1','option2','option3'];
 localStorage.setItem('options', this.optionsArray);
```

Do you know why I am getting an empty value?

Comment: show us how you inserted the data in localstorage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ionic 2 local storage unable to set retrieved value to variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831634/ionic-2-local-storage-unable-to-set-retrieved-value-to-variable)

Comment: I've updated the post, please check it out to know how I set the array

Answer (score 0):

`setItem` is not a member of `LocalStorage`, you must be getting an error when you use it. The correct function is `set(key,value)`, in your case `localStorage.set('options',this.optionsArray)`

docs with an example are here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/storage/LocalStorage/

Comment: Already tried that, we I use `set(key,value)` instead of `setItem` it does not work (i.e I click and it does not move to the next page)

Comment: Then you must be getting an error message or stack trace in the log. Can you post it? You should also share the whole js file.

Comment: The docs are about Ionic's own `Storage()` API, not localStorage. `localStorage.setItem()` is the correct method when you access localStorage directly. The problem is with *getting* the values, not setting them (see the duplicate).