# JavaScript/Ionic2 - Why I can't retrieve the localStorage value?

Tags: javascript, ionic2

I am trying to retrieve the localStorage value; however, I can't get any value and my log looks like the following:

> log is: {}

This is my code so far:

```
import {Storage, LocalStorage} from 'ionic-angular';
//I am storing here
this.local = new Storage(LocalStorage);
this.local.set('options', 'op2'); 
//In the chrome developer tools, I can see that the value was stored successfully in localStorage

//I can't see anything, when trying to retrieve the stored value
console.log('log is : '+ JSON.stringify(this.local.get('options')));
```

Comment: what is LocalStorage and Storage here?

Comment: LocalStorage is imported using the following `import Storage, LocalStorage} from 'ionic-angular';`

Comment: And what about using setItem(...) instead of set(..) and of course then getItem(..).

Comment: Well, in this case it's the exact same as `set()` is a part of ionic2 framework

Comment: That's true, it's Ionic2 Syntax

Comment: Are you calling `this.local.get` from within a separate function by any chance?

Comment: already tried to call `this.local.get` from a separate function, and I got the same results. That's why I am calling now `this.local.get` to debug..

Comment: Uh... Why are you using all of this fancy syntax? Do you plan to use more than the default localStorage.setItem(name,value) and localStorage.getItem(name)?

Comment: I'm only saying because `this` can refer to different objects depending on how it is called. For example if you have functions in an array and call `array[0]()`, the method called will refer to `array` as `this` internally.

Comment: @TheGenieOfTruth I am planning actually, but I am afraid that the default `localStorage` will not work in the mobile version, as I am developing an app using Ionic2/Angular2

Comment: I have used my phone once before on a vanilla JavaScript engine, and localStorage worked fine. I don't have much experience with Ionic2 and Angular2, but I'm pretty sure using vanilla JavaScript should have localStorage working.

Comment: why would you start a new question instead of continuing your own question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37229203/javascript-angular2-localstorage-can-get-anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read value from localStorage in this way:

```
   this.local.get('options').then(value => console.log(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation that I already provided in your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37229203/javascript-angular2-localstorage-can-get-anything) , you'll find that `set` doesn't resolve immediately and instead returns a promise. If you try to `get` immediately instead of waiting for the `Promise` resolution the most likely outcome is that the storage is still empty.